# Illegal binding of built-in syntax: `:`

Tags: haskell, stream

I need to build custom *Stream* data type.
It's like list data type, but for infinite lists only (without empty list possibility).

I found list data type -

```
data [] a = a : [a] | []
```

and I wrote this:

```
data Stream a = a : (Stream a)
```

but GHCi gives error message:

> Illegal binding of built-in syntax: :

what's wrong this my data type declaration?

Comment: `data [] a = a : [a] | []` is just pseduo-syntax. It's not actually valid Haskell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor `(:)` is built-in syntax and specific to the standard list type, unlike much of the standard "built-in" types that are just regular types defined in the standard library.

So, you'll need to use a different constructor for your stream type. `(:|)` and `(:<)` are versions I've seen, so something like this:

```
data Stream a = a :< Stream a
```

...should work fine.

You could also drop the infix constructor entirely if you prefer:

```
data Stream a = Stream a (Stream a)
```

Answer (score 6):

Note: you can use the existing [`Data.Stream.Infinite`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/streams/3.1/doc/html/Data-Stream-Infinite.html) from the [`streams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams) package for this purpose and get a ton of instances and combinators for free, but `(:)` itself is built in syntax.